# AWS Workspaces CLI: Syntax for `Start - Workspaces`

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-workspaces

I am trying to craft a script to start workspaces 10 minutes before the workday begins. I am starting with running the CLI command below and then build from there. I have checked that I am in the right region:

`aws workspaces start-workspaces --start-workspace-requests WorkspaceId=[Workspace ID]`

This command is timing out. It feels like 101 but can't find any references online. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply.  Accidentally found this when looking for something else...

It works without an [array] for the `WorkspaceId` parameter shorthand syntax.  Unless you're passing a JSON, you probably intend to use this method.

```
aws workspaces start-workspaces --start-workspace-requests WorkspaceId=ws-abcd12345
```

Here is the reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workspaces/start-workspaces.html

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'll circle back to the project and test this out. My planned ETA is about 48 hours. Much obliged.

Comment: would you mind marking this as the answer if it was helpful for you @TheDahomean